# Scrapy Import Method from another Spider

Tags: python, scrapy

So I have a scrapy project and I've written two spiders for it. One to scan the whole web page, and one to do daily updates. Is there a way I can import a method from the one the scrapes the whole web site into the one that only does daily update? I'm not very good with the whole module import thing to begin with.

This is what the project structure looks like

```
/Myproject
      __init__.py items.py piplines.py settings.py
    /spiders
        spiderA.py spiderB.py __init__.py
```

I've tried

```
from Myproject.spiders.spiderA import theMethod
```

To no avail.

Comment: I don't think you can import `functions` from inside a .py file only `class`es

Comment: Did you try `from spiderA import theMethod`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from spiderA import theMethod
```

Comment: This was a case of stupidity. The method was inside of the spider class. All I had to do was put my method outside of the class and voila. It works.